# Google Sheets: How do I return the value of a specific cell in a table

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google sheets question i'm hoping to get help with.

I have the following Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d8RYCC5P8WaYurkQc3ylmpSbCz1-tZDm3_FNr6glPM0/edit?usp=sharing

What I would like to do is to allow the user to use the pulldown list boxes ("Price" and "Range) to select a combination and then to populate a cell ("Your Value") with the value identified using the Price/Range selection.

For example of the user selected Price=20-30 and Range=Price2 then the "Your Value" cell should be populated with the value "8".

If anyone can advise how I can do this i'd really appreciate it.

Thank you Google Sheets Experts!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Read about any formulas? Looked into writing a programmatic solution via Apps Script? Or just fishing for someone to do all the work?

Comment: What is your question? Don't you already have the answer in your sheet? If you always have a two-dimensional array that documents/computes the output from two user inputs, using `match()` and `to_text()` are perfectly fine.